# Using Clang to get function definitions

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, clang++, llvm-clang

I would like use clang to get the functions names from a cpp file.
I found some tutorials but always I received this error when I executed 'make':

> /usr/bin/ld: error: ../../lib/libLLVMSelectionDAG.a: ELF section name out of range
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   tools/lto/CMakeFiles/LTO.dir/build.make:269: recipe for target 'lib/libLTO.so.7.0.0svn' failed
>   make[2]: *** [lib/libLTO.so.7.0.0svn] Error 1
>   CMakeFiles/Makefile2:18957: recipe for target 'tools/lto/CMakeFiles/LTO.dir/all' failed
>   make[1]: *** [tools/lto/CMakeFiles/LTO.dir/all] Error 2
>   Makefile:149: recipe for target 'all' failed
>   make: *** [all] Error 2

Any idea of how can I solve this problem or any tutorial?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to give a link to the tutorial or your CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: I am following this: https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html, It fails when I execute the 'make' command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem increasing the /dev/sda1 size and removing the file ../../lib/libLLVMSelectionDAG.a
After that I only executed 'make' and It worked.

Comment: Have you used `gcc` or `clang` to build `clang`?

Comment: I used clang and the specific target.